# SQL Error during Inner Join: "pg_atoi could not be parsed"

Tags: sql, database, parsing, join, data-manipulation

I tried to write the following code:

```
create table new_table as select table_1."var_1", table_2."var_2" from table_1
inner join table_2 on table_1."var_1"= table_2."var_2" ;
```

But this returned the following error (note: "abc123" is one of the values contained in "var_1"):

```
pg_atoi: error in "abc123" : can't parse
```

However, when I slightly modified the above code:

```
create table new_table as select table_1."var_1", table_2."var_2" from table_1
inner join table_2 on table_1."var_1"= '' || table_2."var_2" ;
```

Suddenly the code works fine!

**My Question:**

- Does anyone know what "pg_atoi error" refers to (I found some links but I am not sure if I understand them, e.g. https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/KB42250-quot-ERROR-pg-atoi-error-in-quot-2011-01-quot-cant-parse?language=en_US)?
- Does anyone know why adding `'' ||` fixes the problem?
- In general, can someone please tell me what is this error about, why is it produced and how it can be fixed? Is the answer I am using legitimately fixing this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this
table_1."var_1"::char(200)= table_2."var_2"::char(200)
In join.
This is caused by wront automatic casting.
Int ||'' = varchar. Problem in thay you are trying to compare text with number (one of this colimn is number another i text).
And more if all data in text xolumn can be cast for number this error wont appear. (that why join with differnt data tyles  are dangerous)